# "failed to find any PEM data in certificate input" error popup by tls.X509KeyPair

Tags: go, ssl

I am trying to make are tls cert for HTTPS server by golang x509 package

and i got this error

> tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input

After some research, I create my Cert like this

```
func Generatecert()  {
    ca := &x509.Certificate{
        SerialNumber: big.NewInt(2023),
        Subject: pkix.Name{
            Organization:       []string{"Company"},
            OrganizationalUnit: []string{"lol"},
            Country:            []string{"US"},
            Province:           []string{""},
            Locality:           []string{"NY"},
            StreetAddress:      []string{"No street"},
            PostalCode:         []string{"77777"},
        },
        NotBefore:             time.Now(),
        NotAfter:              time.Now().AddDate(10, 0, 0),
        SubjectKeyId:          []byte{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        BasicConstraintsValid: true,
        IsCA:                  true,
        ExtKeyUsage:           []x509.ExtKeyUsage{x509.ExtKeyUsageClientAuth, x509.ExtKeyUsageServerAuth},
        KeyUsage:              x509.KeyUsageDigitalSignature | x509.KeyUsageCertSign,
    }

    certpubl, certpriv, err := ed25519.GenerateKey(rand.Reader)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("key generate failed", err)
        return
    }

    certCert, err := x509.CreateCertificate(rand.Reader, ca, ca, certpubl, certpriv)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("create cert failed", err)
        return
    }

    out := &bytes.Buffer{}

    //Encoding cert
    certtestpem := &pem.Block{Type: "CERTIFICATE", Bytes: certCert}
    pem.Encode(out, certtestpem)
    publicCert := out.Bytes()
    certDERBlock, publicCert := pem.Decode(publicCert)

    //Check Decoded cert
    print(certDERBlock.Type, "\n")
    if publicCert != nil {
        print("publicCert nil\n")
    }

    //Encoding Private Key
    out.Reset()
    privatepem, _ := x509.MarshalPKCS8PrivateKey(certpriv)
    pem.Encode(out, &pem.Block{Type: "PRIVATE KEY", Bytes: privatepem})
    privitKey := out.Bytes()

    //check KeyPair
    _, err = tls.X509KeyPair(publicCert, privitKey)
    if err != nil {
        print(err.Error())
    }
}
```

it show the error like under

> CERTIFICATE
>
> publicCert nil
>
> tls: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input

I try Decode after pem.EncodeToMemory

the pem.Type are correct, but variable "publicCert" is nil, And I try add are \n begin of the cert, it did nothing, but the cert itself is not nil, Can Somebody Help me with this

What sould I do to make a working Tls???

Comment: I don't have the problem you see. But this is not the code you are actually running, since this would not compile. Please provide a __minimal but complete__ example instead which allows others to reproduce your problem.

Comment: thank you for helping, I just edit it to little complete status, it this work??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in this code

> ```
> publicCert := out.Bytes()
> ```

Checking the content of `publicCert` at this stage shows the expect value. But the following statement will simply overwrite `publicCert`:

> ```
> certDERBlock, publicCert := pem.Decode(publicCert)
> ```

This can be seen by checking `publicCert` after this statement. [As documented](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/pem#Encode) `publicCert` will now show the data after the actual certificate.

It should be instead

```
certDERBlock, _ := pem.Decode(publicCert)
```

Checking the content of `publicCert` after this corrected statement shows the expected value again.

> ```
> out.Reset()
> privatepem, _ := x509.MarshalPKCS8PrivateKey(certpriv)
> pem.Encode(out, &pem.Block{Type: "PRIVATE KEY", Bytes: privatepem})
> privitKey := out.Bytes()
> ```

This will get the expected value into `privitKey`.  But, it will change `publicCert` since it is just a slice of `out` and `out` has been changed the the operations. Thus `out` will now contain at the beginning the `privitKey` and no longer the start of the certificate - and this is reflected in the value of `publicCert`.

See also [the documentation for bytes.Buffer.Bytes](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#Buffer.Bytes)

> The slice is **valid for use only until the next buffer modification** (that is, only until the next call to a method like Read, Write, Reset, or Truncate)

So instead of just resetting the existing buffer

> ```
> out.Reset()
> ```

it would be better to create a new buffer for `privitKey` and keep the existing one for `publicCert`

> ```
> out = &bytes.Buffer{}
> ```

Comment: thanks , it is the bytes.buffer got change effect the publicCert.

Answer (score 0):

after some debug, it seem like the pem.Encode function not working for me,

so i change it to pem.EncodeToMemory and it working thank you for the help.